# PageSpeed Insights on Google Sheets is running very slowly for multiple URLs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I currently run a daily export on Google Sheets using Google PageSpeed Insights. More URLs have been added recently and instead of taking around 30 seconds per URL (with just one), it is now taking 1 min which exceed the 6 minutes maximum from Google Scripts.

I modified a code to add a loop to include multiple URLs. Is it because I call too many times the function CALLPAGESPEED ? Do you have a simple optimization ?

Here's the code :

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var pageSpeedApiKey = scriptProperties.getProperty('PSI_API_KEY');
var pageSpeedMonitorUrls = [
  'https://www.metro.ca/en/online-grocery',
  'https://voila.ca/',
  'https://www.loblaws.ca/',
  'https://www.walmart.ca/en',
  'https://www.amazon.ca/',
  'https://www.grocerygateway.com/store/groceryGateway/en/',
  'https://www.iga.net/en/online_grocery'
];

function monitor() {
  for (var i = 0; i < pageSpeedMonitorUrls.length; i++) {
  var url = pageSpeedMonitorUrls[i];
  var desktop = callPageSpeed(url,'desktop');
  var mobile = callPageSpeed(url,'mobile');
  displaydata(url,desktop,mobile);
  }
}

function callPageSpeed(url,strategy) {
  var pageSpeedUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=' + url + '&key=' + pageSpeedApiKey + '&strategy=' + strategy;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageSpeedUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
}


function displaydata(url,desktop,mobile){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.appendRow([
    Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'HH'),      
    url,
    desktop['lighthouseResult']['categories']['performance']['score'] * 100,
    desktop['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['firstContentfulPaint']/1000,
    desktop['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['speedIndex']/1000,
    desktop['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['interactive']/1000,
    mobile['lighthouseResult']['categories']['performance']['score'] * 100,
    mobile['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['firstContentfulPaint']/1000,
    mobile['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['speedIndex']/1000,
    mobile['lighthouseResult']['audits']['metrics']['details']['items'][0]['interactive']/1000
                  ]);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you will need to run them asynchronously as 14 requests one after the other will nearly always time out. If you run them asynchronously you could set each one running with only a second between each test and then gather the results at the end. Unfortunately I do not know google-apps to be able to advise how to adjust your code. Maybe https://gist.github.com/sdesalas/2972f8647897d5481fd8e01f03122805 will help you work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the execution time of your script by changing the way that the data is added to the spreadsheet.

The function `displayData` adds the data by using `appendRow` and it's included inside the for loop. This makes your script slow.

One way to improve the performance is to change `displayData` to build an Array of *rows* (let call `values`), then, after the loop, add all the *rows* at once by using `setValues(values)`

---

You might also try `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll` instead of `UrlFechApp.fetch` so with single call to the URL Fetch Service you can get the responses for all the URLs.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests